# Getting merged/unified entries from ABAddressBook

Tags: objective-c, ios4, linked-list, contacts, addressbook

I'm developing an application that is showing the iPhone contacts.

The ABAddressBookRef returns duplicate entries for a contact that appears only once in the iPhone contacts application.

Looking on the contact card (from the iPhone contacts), in the bottom there is a section called "Linked Contacts" so obviously apple "merge"/"unify" these two entries into the one i see.

The question here is what is the best way to mimic the same behavior so my app will show only one entry? is there an API that returns the merged/unified entries from the address book?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To create a list of contacts that merges in linked contacts:

Note: ABPerson references are stored in custom **Person** class instances.  All persons are then stored in a dictionary **addressBookDictionary** using **recordID** of each person as the key.

---

**1. Get all ABPersons using ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople.**  Store persons in allPersonRecords array.

**2. Iterate through all ABPersons.**

---

**2.1 Get a list of linked persons for each ABPerson.** Use

> ABPersonCopyArrayOfAllLinkedPeople(ABRecordRef person);

If there are no linked contacts, this method will return an array including the person reference him/herself.  So if the return array has a count > 1, the person has linked contacts.

**2.2 Add the linked persons to a NSMutableSet.**  These linked persons will be skipped and not processed in future iterations.

**2.3 Create a Person instance for the current ABPerson.**

**2.4 Merge linked person information into Person instance.** A linked person may have different phone numbers, so you need to merge them together.

---

```
NSArray *allPersonRecords = (NSArray *) ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(self.addressBook);
NSMutableSet *linkedPersonsToSkip = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];

for (int i=0; i<[allPersonRecords count]; i++){

    ABRecordRef personRecordRef = [allPersonRecords objectAtIndex:i];

    // skip if contact has already been merged
    //
    if ([linkedPersonsToSkip containsObject:personRecordRef]) {
        continue;
    }

    // Create object representing this person
    //
    Person *thisPerson = [[Person alloc] initWithPersonRef:personRecordRef];

    // check if there are linked contacts & merge their contact information
    //
    NSArray *linked = (NSArray *) ABPersonCopyArrayOfAllLinkedPeople(personRecordRef);
    if ([linked count] > 1) {
        [linkedPersonsToSkip addObjectsFromArray:linked];

        // merge linked contact info
        for (int m = 0; m < [linked count]; m++) {
            ABRecordRef iLinkedPerson = [linked objectAtIndex:m];
            // don't merge the same contact
            if (iLinkedPerson == personRecordRef) {
                continue;
            }
            [thisPerson mergeInfoFromPersonRef:iLinkedPerson];
        }
    }
    [self.addressBookDictionary setObject:thisPerson forKey:thisPerson.recordID];
    [thisPerson release];
    [linked release];
}
[linkedPersonsToSkip release];
[allPersonRecords release];
```

Comment: hi , can you please describe what Person class contains in your code ?

Comment: Please Describe - Person Class not found .. @MinTsai

Comment: The Person class is just his custom class for storing contact information for each person, it basically matched the format of my own (except naming). initWithPersonRef will call AbRecordCopyValue on personRecordRef for fields it wants to store and saves them to instance variables/properties created in the Person object. Don't cut/paste code without understanding it, you will create far bigger problems for yourself in the long run when you actually have to maintain the code. And thanks to Harris for offering up the solution to this problem.

Comment: Do you think there can be a better way to achieve this if we have huge number of contacts...say 5000? Thanks.

Comment: Where is the method? mergeInfoFromPersonRef? Or are we suppose to write this ourselves?

Comment: @sole007 I have the same issue, where solutions like these don't really scale well. Once you pass the 2k contact mark, this gets expensive. Until Apple provides a native way of doing this, I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 7):

You need to have a look at a function named:

CFArrayRef ABPersonCopyArrayOfAllLinkedPeople(ABRecordRef person);

This function is defined in ABPerson.h.  You pass in an ABRecordRef for a person and the function returns an array of ABRecordRef objects representing the address book cards that are linked to the person you passed in.

1. Make a mutable copy of the array containing the address book entries that were returned from the ABAddressBookRef.  For the sake of discussion, call this new array "finalContacts".
2. Iterate over the original array of contacts.
3. For each entry in the array, call the above function and pass in the current entry.  You will get out a list of linked ABPersonRef objects.  Remove all of these entries from the "finalContacts" array.
4. After iteration, all linked cards should be removed from "finalContacts" and you should be left with a unique list of address book cards.

Comment: sounds fair enough.. but maybe we should have a look at what the linked contacts is good for?

Comment: also removing "mom", "assistent" and other links from displaying in the list sounds weird..(?)

Comment: @hfossli: `ABPersonCopyArrayOfAllLinkedPeople(person)` returns an array of other records for the same person.  The links to Spouse, Assistant, etc. are returned by `ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonRelatedNamesProperty)`.